# Posts showing up different sizes on Tumblr

Tags: html, themes, tumblr

First post here, can't seem to get a narrow enough search to really help me figure this out. So I've edited a theme to look how I want, but the strange thing is that my photosets display as 500px as I want, but single photos display a lot smaller until you go to their individual post (where you see notes on the single post) and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Same goes for any text posts and god forbid I post any videos. It's all aesthetics but it is driving me crazy! I've looked through all of the block:post/quote/picture etc but I can't find any size variables to edit therein. Any help will be great! Here's the pastebin code for my entire theme's HTML: http://pastebin.com/G1STM1LX

The max width only goes up to 350px from the theme's options but I got the photosets to work by editing them within their own block. I know a bit of HTML but this is driving me bonkers!

Comment: Please trim down your HTML. Do you really expect us to read this?

Comment: I figured it would go without saying to ctrl+f and find the blocks.. Plus I'd hate to trim down something having a script that might be taking over and thus making it unsolvable.

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual blog?

Answer (score 1):

looked through your code and figured you could do it with CSS.

The problem is in this part:

```
#content .entry img{
{block:IndexPage}
{block:if300pxWidth}max-width:300px;{/block:if300pxWidth}
{block:if250pxWidth}max-width:250px;{/block:if250pxWidth}
{block:if200pxWidth}max-width:200px;{/block:if200pxWidth}
{block:if350pxWidth}max-width:350px;{/block:if350pxWidth}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}max-width:500px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
}
```

You'll notice that there are max-widths set when you are in the blog's index. It resizes the image generated by the {PhotoURL-500} block. A quick fix would require you to change this:

```
{block:if350pxWidth}max-width:350px;{/block:if350pxWidth}
```

to this:

```
{block:if350pxWidth}max-width:500px;{/block:if350pxWidth}
```